# Show $c_{00}$ is not closed under supremum norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Show $Y=c_{00}$ is not closed under $(\ell^{\infty}, \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$.

---

I know that I need to find a $(y_n) \in c_{00}$ such that this converges to $y$ with $y \notin c_{00}$. So we need $\|y_n -y \|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$ such that $y \notin c_{00}$ but I can't find any example.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...) \notin c_{00}$, $y_1=(1,0,0,...)$, $y_2=(1,\frac{1}{2},0,0,...)$ and so on. $y_n \in c_{00}$ and $\|y_n -y \|_{\infty}=\frac{1}{n+1}$ which tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Why can't we just have $y_n=(1,\frac12,..., \frac1n,0,0,...) \in c_{00}$ and $y=(1, \frac12,..., \frac1n, \frac1{n+1},...) \notin c_{00}$. Then $\|y_n-y \|_{\infty} = \|(0,...,0,\frac1{n+1}, \frac1{n+2},...)\|_{\infty}= \frac1{n+1}$ which tends to zero when $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: Yes that's it I just did not not wrote it in a formal way.